Access a class from one local package through another local package
I have the following structure for two local packages:
├── lib
├── packages
│ ├── auth_api
│ └── auth_repository

auth_api package is used in auth_repository package through pubspec.yaml and auth_repository is used in lib/ through the root level pubspec.yaml. There's a class called AuthFailure in auth_api class that I want to access in lib/.
Is there a way to do this without adding auth_api to the root level pubspec.yaml just to access one class? Maybe to access it through the already added auth_repository package??

You can re-export items you import, and control it with show/hide.

Based on the comment from @Randal Schwartz:
Add the following in the auth_repository/lib/auth_repository.dart file:
export 'package:auth_api/auth_api.dart' show AuthFailure;

Remember, AuthFailure should be exported in auth_api/lib/auth_api.dart.
